# Query DateTime without milliseconds

Tags: sql-server

I have this simple code

```
SELECT * 
FROM AnalogHistory 
WHERE Tagname = 'L3831_kg' 
  AND DATEDIFF(DAY, [DateTime], '2018-03-13 15:04:05.0110000') = 0
```

I am trying to query my `DateTime` column without milliseconds, but I keep getting this error

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Any help?

Thank you

Comment: I am guessing that the column DateTime is not a datetime datatype but instead some sinister thing like varchar? That means you have some value in there that is not a valid datetime.

Comment: @SeanLange yes i think so too but i have tried to convert it, to use different ways to handle it but it's not working?

Answer (score 0):

Actually i Found the Problem, the Query is fine it's just the format of the DateTime in the query

```
DATEDIFF(DAY, [DateTime], '2018-03-13 15:04:05.011') = 0
```

once removing the extra zeros it works fine